# Animation not rendered properly in android

Tags: android, listview

I am moving a listview upwards, but after it has moves the traces of previous instance of view remains there. How can i get rid of it. I have tried invalidating the main layout but no use. Plz guide.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcKpJu8zWe8&feature=youtu.be

thx

```
                    r = new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){

                            TranslateAnimation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, mbar4.getTop(), -mbar4.getBottom());
                            translateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
                            translateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);


                            mbar4.startAnimation(translateAnimation);
                            st4.startAnimation(translateAnimation);

                            Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, PullListView.getTop(), -PullListView.getTop());
                            animation.setDuration(1000);
                            animation.setFillAfter(true);


                            PullListView.startAnimation(animation);
                            PullListView.invalidate();


                        }
                       }
                };

                h.removeCallbacks(r);
                h.postDelayed(r, 5000);
```

Comment: Please post some code, so that we can help you out.